# Scroll page at last slide (fullscreen vertical scroller)

Tags: jquery, api, revolution-slider

Is there a way to scroll below a slider once the slider reaches the last slide? Themepunch said it's possible via the API, but they didn't explain any further.

Ultimately, I'd like to use the slider (fullscreen slider with multiple slides) at the top of the page on intro, mouse wheel/scroll through a couple slides, then continue on down the page.

They're not using rev slider, but Here's an example of the functionality: http://www.gogoro.com/smartscooter/faster

Also, if able to figure this out, having the ability to have a page that you scroll down a section or two; then when you hit the slider section it scrolls through the sliders on mouse wheel and when all the slides are done it moves on to the next section.

Check out this site for an example: https://www.fitbit.com/surge

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: My apologies, Andreas, I didn't realize that was a no-no. I honestly wasn't trying to force a tag there-was trying to be informative. Thanks for the edit and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article I wrote about [how to create a page like HugeInc](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/04/09/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/).
It looks very similar to [the one you add as an example of what you want](http://www.gogoro.com/smartscooter/faster).

For it I made use of my plugin [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/).

You probably don't want to follow the whole tutorial as it is, but you can get some concepts as the one of the last section.

Comment: Good stuff. This could definitely work. Thanks, @Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not the most elegant solution but in these cases I make another slide and I put my html that I would put in normal page in a new text/html layer of the slider. So this last slide looks like a page but actually is a slider.  Positive thing about this that everything will behave and resize on different screens in the same way. Rev slider 5 has also cool ways to handle mobile so actually there is no reason why not to build everything in the slider, especially if you have only small sections that should be normally in the page.